# help sorting the program

Tags: java

I need to print out the elements of a sorted array and also write them to a file. It's an array of objects of Customer class(my own deifinition). The Customer[] review consists of a max of 30 of these objects. Now, the problem is I need the number of elements in the array to do this but I can't pass that variable to the methods as it's not a part of the main method nor is it a global variable. The methods are called in the menu method. Both WriteFile and DisplayRecords use num_records. The reason I'm having this problem is because earlier I didn't have the menu method and simply carried the operations out from the main method but apparently the menu method is required. I apologize in advance if the problem seems vague.

```
public static int readFile(String filename, Customer[] review)throws IOException{

          int count=0;
          Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File (filename));

          /*Reading the first record separatly*/
                      Customer first = new Customer();

                      String[] a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_account_id(Integer.parseInt(a[1].trim()));

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_name(a[1].toUpperCase().trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_address(a[1].trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_phone_number(a[1].trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_date_of_birth(a[1].trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_balance(Double.parseDouble(a[1].trim()));


                      scan.nextLine();// resets the buffer reader
                      review[0]= first;
                      count = count+1;

                      while (scan.hasNext()&& count>0){
                      Customer temp = new Customer();

                      String[] st = scan.nextLine().split("=");

                       for(int i=1;i<count;i++){
                             if(Integer.parseInt(st[1].trim())== review[i].get_accountid()){ // checking for duplicate records
                                  System.out.println("This account id is already in use so the record won't be read");
                                  for (int k=0; k<7; k++)
                                       scan.nextLine();
                          }
                             else
                                break;
                     }

                      temp.set_account_id(Integer.parseInt(st[1].trim()));
                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_name(st[1].toUpperCase().trim());
                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_address(st[1].trim());
                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_phone_number(st[1].trim());
                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_date_of_birth(st[1].trim());
                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_balance(Double.parseDouble(st[1].trim()));

                      if (scan.hasNextLine()){
                          scan.nextLine();
                          }

                     int j;
                     for(j=0;j<count;j++){

                            if (temp.get_name().compareTo(review[j].get_name())<0){ // Putting records in ascending order
                                break;
                            }
                         }

                      count=count+1;
                      for (int k=count;k>j;k--){
                          review[k]=review[k-1];
                      }

                      review[j]= temp;

                         if (count>=30){
                         System.out.println("The number of records read has exceeded the limit and it will stop reading now");
                         break;
              }

        }

        return count;
   }


      public static void displayRecords(Customer[] review, int num_records){
          for (int k=0; k< num_records; k++){
              System.out.println(review[k].get_name());
              System.out.println(review[k].get_balance());
              System.out.println(review[k].get_accountid());
              System.out.println(review[k].get_date_of_birth());
              System.out.println(review[k].get_address());
              System.out.println(review[k].get_phone_number());


          }
  }

  public static int writeFile(Customer[] review, int num_records ) throws IOException{
      int count=0;
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("newCustomers.txt"));
      for (int i=0; i<num_records;i++){
              out.write("Name = " + review[i].get_name()+ "\r\n");
              out.write("Balance = " +(int)review[i].get_balance() + "\r\n");
              out.write("Accoutn Id = " + review[i].get_accountid() + "\r\n");
              out.write("DOB = " + review[i].get_date_of_birth() + "\r\n");
              out.write("Address = " + review[i].get_address() + "\r\n");
              out.write("Phone Number = " + review[i].get_phone_number() + "\r\n");
              out.newLine();
              count++;
      }
              out.close();
              return count;
  }


      public static void menu(Customer[] records)throws IOException{
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         int choice;
         Boolean loopcont= true;
         while (loopcont){
              System.out.println("1. To Read the data");
              System.out.println("2. To Display the date");
              System.out.println("3. To Write the data");
              System.out.println("4. Exit");
              System.out.println("Enter your choice");
              choice = in.nextInt();
          switch (choice) {
                  case 1: {
                       String filename;
                       System.out.println("Enter the filename for the input file");
                       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                       filename = reader.readLine();
                       int num_records=0;
                       try{
                           num_records= readFile(filename,records);
                           System.out.println("The number of records read = " + num_records);
                      }
                      catch(IOException e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                      break;
                  }
                  case 2: {
                        displayRecords(records,num_records);
                        break;

                  }
                 case 3: {
                     int num_rec_written =  writeFile(records,num_records);
                     System.out.println("The number of records writeen = " + num_rec_written);
                     break;
                 }

                case 4: {
                     loopcont = false;
                     break;
                }

               default: {
                   System.out.println("Incorrect input. Kindly enter again");
                    break;
               }
             }

          }

         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`review.length` will give you the number of entries in the Customer array, this might solve your problem, another way to go would be to use the foreach loop

```
for(Customer c : review){
    // c is each customer in the array
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it ends up printing the empty array elements too. this is probably due to my declaration of the array with 30 customer class elements and I used the default constructor on them? Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @dawnoflife in your code above your readFile method is missing, your mistake might be there

Comment: put in the readfile. the method works fine. its the declaration of the array that's giving me the problem. i run through a loop for 30 and call the default constructor for each. if i don't do this i get a NullPointerExcption

Comment: how can i avoid getting the extra elements then?

Comment: how is the scanner gonna work if i'm not reading anything but merely accessing elements from an array? i tried it and it continues infinitely

Comment: have a look at the second example: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/scanning-text-with-java.util.scanner-3.html

Comment: You should stop if the scanner doesn't find a next entry and your `readFile` probably should return the Customer array instead of just filling entries into an existing one. Thus you could also return an array of length 2 if there are only 2 entries in the file.

Comment: my readfile does stop when there is no more input. i can't return the array back as i NEED to return the number of records read to the user. @ sharpner: i still don't get where do you want me to implement that as I don't want to deal with the file manipulation in my writeFile and display methods.

Answer (score 0):

If `num_records` is the size of the array, then `num_records = review.length` is true, so no need to pass `num_records` explicitly.

Note that in Java 5+, you can do the following:

```
for (Customer customer : review){
          System.out.println(customer .get_name());
          System.out.println(customer .get_balance());
          System.out.println(customer .get_accountid());
          System.out.println(customer .get_date_of_birth());
          System.out.println(customer .get_address());
          System.out.println(customer .get_phone_number());
}
```

Comment: it's not simply an array but an array of objects. the review arr is defined with 30 of these objects. i edited the question.

Comment: can i get some documentation on the usage of ":"?

Comment: It's called the `foreach` loop and part of the language. Here's a <a href="http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html">result</a> from a quick google query.

Comment: "it's not simply an array but an array of objects" - Well, almost any array in Java is an array of objects (except for arrays of primitive types, of course) :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question, just get the length of the array!  i.e.

```
 int num_recourds = review.length;
```

Comment: sharpner's reply is the one to go with to use in you usage case

Answer (score 0):

There is answer above and i want to give you some advice. Try to avoid this code in your application:

```
      System.out.println(customer .get_name());
      System.out.println(customer .get_balance());
      System.out.println(customer .get_accountid());
      System.out.println(customer .get_date_of_birth());
      System.out.println(customer .get_address());
      System.out.println(customer .get_phone_number());
```

Replace it with `Customer.getString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a collection class (like ArrayList) instead of an array? This class encapsulates the number of elements as well as the elements itself.